# Scala Appending to an empty Array

Tags: scala

I am trying to append to an array but for some reason it is just appending blanks into my Array.

```
  def schemaClean(x: Array[String]): Array[String] =
  {
    val array = Array[String]()
    for(i <- 0 until x.length){
      val convert = x(i).toString
      val split = convert.split('|')
      if (split.length == 5) {
        val drop = split.dropRight(3).mkString(" ")
        array :+ drop
      }
      else if (split.length == 4) {
        val drop = split.dropRight(2).mkString(" ")
        println(drop)
        array :+ drop.toString
        println(array.mkString(" "))
      }
    }
   array
  }


  val schema1 = schemaClean(schema)
```

prints this:

```
record_id string

assigned_offer_id string

accepted_offer_flag string

current_offer_flag string
```

If I try and print schema1 its just 1 blank line.

Comment: You are not storing the new array's reference anywhere. (`array :+ drop`, `array :+ drop.toString`) `array` should be a `var` imho (or use fold/...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala's `Array` size is immutable. From [Scala's reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array):

```
def
    :+(elem: A): Array[A]
```

> > [use case] A copy of this array with an element appended.

Thus `:+` returns a new array whose reference you are not using.

```
val array = ...
```

Should be:

```
var array = ...
```

And you should update that reference with the new arrays obtained after each append operation.

Since there are not variable size arrays in Scala, the alternative to an `Array` `var` copied after insertion is [BufferArray](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html), use its method operator `+=` to append new elements and obtain the resulting array from the buffer, e.g:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
val ab = ArrayBuffer[String]()
ab += "hello"
ab += "world"
ab.toArray
```

> res2: Array[String] = Array(hello, world)

Applied to your code:

```
def schemaClean(x: Array[String]): Array[String] =
  {
    val arrayBuf = ArrayBuffer[String]()
    for(i <- 0 until x.length){
      val convert = x(i).toString
      val split = convert.split('|')
      if (split.length == 5) {
        val drop = split.dropRight(3).mkString(" ")
        arrayBuf += drop
      }
      else if (split.length == 4) {
        val drop = split.dropRight(2).mkString(" ")
        println(drop)
        arrayBuf += drop.toString
        println(arrayBuf.toArray.mkString(" "))
      }
    }
   arrayBuf.toArray
  }
```

Comment: Wonderful thank you for not only giving the answer but also explaining why! New to this language and its subtle nuances!

Comment: A bit of a correction: Scala arrays are NOT immutable. As in Java, the _length_ of a Scala array cannot be modified, so `:+` necessarily creates a copy. But arrays can be updated in-place with statements like `myArray(0) = newVal;`. You'll get yourself into all kinds of trouble if you treat arrays as immutable and therefore thread-safe.

Comment: @SteveWaldman Thanks for the observation, I've edited my answer to include the correction.